# How to remove some array in mongodb with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the data like this

```js
{
  "_id": "61794cfbbe84b5f1f8ae4e16",
  "image": "www.imagetest.com",
  "title": "test pembuatan artikel",
  "category": [
    "informasi",
    "budidaya"
  ],
  "description": "tes artikel",
  "createdAt": "2021-10-27T12:58:35.969Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-11-06T01:49:06.012Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

i want to remove some category from category arrays by selected _id. I have tried $pull but it does not change in my database. I've tried with $pull update method like this:

```js
deleteCategory: async (req, res, next) => {
  const { articleId } = req.params
  const { category } = req.body.category
  try {
    await Article.updateOne(
      {_id: articleId},
      { $pull: {category: category}}
    )
    res.json({
      message: 'Article deleted successfully!',
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: 'An error Occured!',
    })
  }
}
```

with this route:

```js
router.delete('/category/delete/:articleId', ArticleController.deleteCategory)
```

Anyone knows what i'm missing?

Comment: Can you show parsed `category` value? And your sample document for `category` is array of **string (in array pattern)**.

Comment: To remove that category it would need to be `{$pull: {category: "[informasi, budidaya]"}}`.  Does that match the value of `category` in the call?

Comment: the parsed category value is like this:
"category": [
          "informasi",
          "budidaya"]

Comment: the call i input the _id in 61794cfbbe84b5f1f8ae4e16 in path and 
{
  "category": "informasi"
}
in the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know what just happen, but i tried this and it works. I'm pretty sure i've tried this before and it's not working, but i tried this again and it works

```js
const { articleId } = req.params
    
try {
  await Article.updateOne(
    {_id: articleId},
    { $pull: {category: req.body.category}}
  )
  res.json({
    message: 'Article deleted successfully!',
  })
} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).json({
    message: 'An error Occured!',
  })
}
```

Comment: `req.body.category` looks like it is an array, not an object so when you try to assign it to `const { category }` it is undefined since it's expecting an object.